# Silver Efex-like alternative for Linux?

Tags: black-and-white, software-recommendation

Without a doubt, Silver Efex makes Black & White processing easier.
Sometimes I work on Linux, and too bad Silver Efex only runs on Windows & Mac (haven't try Wine, though).

The "de-facto" image processing app on Linux is GIMP. Perhaps there are some GIMP scripts which emulate Silver Efex? Or another app?

Comment: Related (I think): https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/96977/any-way-to-use-nik-software-under-linux

Comment: GIMP is the de facto general purpose image processing application, but I think Darktable is the de facto Lightroom equivalent.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Darktable or RawTherapee.

Comment: Related: [Anything akin to Silver Efex Pro for processing high quality B&W on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/766478)

Comment: I think I found one: GIMP + [G'MIC](https://gmic.eu). G'MIC has interesting BW film presets like Ilford XP2, Kodak Tri-X 400, etc. Maybe not as polished as Silver Efex, but hey I think it's pretty good.